# How to copy index.php into all Subfolders and all Subdirectories of every Subfolder?

Tags: linux, macos

I have the below Mac command which can copy `index.php` into all subdirectories inside the `/Library/WebServer/Documents`:

```
for i in /Library/WebServer/Documents/*
do
    if [ -d "$i" ] # if it's a directory
    then
        sudo cp /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php "$i" 
    fi
done
```

How to copy the `index.php` inside all subfolders (`and their subfolders too`) of the subfolders of `/Library/WebServer/Documents`?

For example,

`/Library/WebServer/Documents/folder1/folder2`, `/Library/WebServer/Documents/folder1/folder2/folder3/`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /Library/WebServer/Documents/ -type d -exec cp /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php {} \;
```

should make it. You will probably get a warning about `/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php` being identical to itself. Ignore it, it's just that `find` tried to copy `/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php` to `/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php` and `cp` found that they are the same file.